# Simple uniform convergence quesiton

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Suppose f converges to f uniformly on $[0,L]$.
Suppose |$f_{n}(x)$| ≤ $h(x)$ on $[0,\infty]$.
Show |$f(x)$|≤ $h(x)$ on $[0,\infty]$.

This is probably really simple, I just can't wrap my head around why. Just wondered if someone could give me a simple explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just take limit on both sides as $n \to \infty$. Pointwise convergence is enough for this.

Comment: Ah I see thank you, I thought because it was uniform I couldn't do pointwise

Comment: @thomas_stafford_22 Uniform convergence is a stronger form of convergence. It implies pointwise convergence.